# Take a walk vs walk

Tags: grammar

Can we say that I am going to take a walk instead of taking the bus? Or should we say I am going to walk instead of taking the bus?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To "take a walk" implies more that you aren't going anywhere. For example, you might take a walk to enjoy a nice day or to clear your head. In your context, it makes more sense to say that you are *going to walk* somewhere.

Comment: I recently found out that take a walk means many different things. Can we use it in directions, for example: Go for four blocks, you will see a market, take a walk across the super market and turn left..

Comment: No. You might say "go for four blocks, walk across the super market" but "take a walk" implies you're just walking for the sake of walking